# Why can't I access a global JS variable in cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm sorry, this might be a very noobish question, and has probably already been asked. I can't find a post answering my specific problem however, so I'm still asking there.

Note that I'm totally new to javascript, I come from object oriented programming languages. Keep that in ming when answering please!

I want my cordova application to connect to a websocket server. Since my app works only for android 4.4 and above, I figured out it would be a good idea to use javascript's window.WebSocket object. So I created a "global" variable like this:

```
var socket = null;
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    ...
}
```

I can sucessfully create a websocket object using the following code:

```
websocketSetup: function() {
    var serverUrl = "ws://echo.websocket.org";
    var logdiv = document.getElementById("logs");
    //Called when the client opents the conection to the server
    var onOpen = function() {
        logdiv.innerHTML += "<p class='purple'>Websocket opened: " + serverUrl + "</p>";
        socket.send("Hello");//FIXME: remove this line
    };
    //Called when the client or the server drops the connection, or sends a close request
    var onClose = function() {
        logdiv.innerHTML += "<p class='purple'>Websocket closed.</p>";
        socket = null;
    };
    //Called when the client recieves a request from the server
    var onMessage = function(event) {
        logdiv.innerHTML += "<p class='purple'>Message:" + event.data + "</p>";
    };
    //Called from the client websocket implementation when an error happens
    var onError = function(event) {
        logdiv.innerHTML += "<p class='purple'>" + event.data + "</p>";
    };
    try{
        socket = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");

                socket.onopen = onOpen;
                socket.onclose = onClose;
                socket.onmessage = onMessage;
                socket.onerror = onError;
    }catch(e){
        logdiv.innerHTML += "<p class='red'>" + e + "</p>";
    }
},
```

This works just fine, I successfully get the echo from the echo websocket server.
However, I'm not able to access this socket variable anymore after. Functions like:

```
socketMessage: function(outgoingmessage) {
    socket.send(outgoingmessage);
    var logdiv = document.getElementById("logs");
    logdiv.innerHTML += "<p class='purple'>Message sent to WS:" + outgoingmessage + "</p>";
}
```

simply doesn't work, as soon as I refer to the socket variable, the function stops it's execution. It also doesn't throw an exception I can try/catch.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found the problem, it was mostly due to my poor knowledge of javascript.

The socket variable doesn't exist anymore after app initialization, because it wasn't set as a global variable properly.

```
socket = null;
```

This code will add the socket variable as a property of the global object, and will make it persistant and accessible from everywhere.